# use shell pipe output as calculator input

Tags: shell, unix, bc

I'm having issues to use the output of a pipe such as

`ls *.gz | wc -l / 2 | bc`

immidiately as input to a shell calculator tool such as `bc`. I'm not sure how to put the quotation marks or if this is possible at all without assigning a variable?

The background is that in the folder each two files belong together, so I simply want to divide the total number of files by 2.

There might be an obvious solution but I could not find it so far...

I'm using `bash` if that is important?

Comment: FYI, parsing `ls` is not a good way to count files (or do almost anything else). `shopt -s nullglob; files=( *.gz ); bc <<<"${#files[@]} / 2"` -- see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: That said, if you're just doing integer division, why use `bc` at all? `echo "$(( ${#files[@]} / 2 ))"` uses only bash-builtin math.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004), which is directly on-point for counting files, and [BashFAQ #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022), on floating-point math.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: so based on the link regarding the parsing issue, would it be safer to use `ls -l` and subtract 1 of the `wc -l`? To your other comments: I only heard about `bc` and the things you suggested work fine, but I would have never come up with that. Also it would be nice to not generate a variable such as `files` for this task. Thank you for the links!

Comment: `printf '%s\0' *.gz | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c` avoids letting the filename impact the result (so you can't have a version of `ls` that doesn't escape literal newlines cause a file created with `touch $'foo\nbar'` to be counted twice), but it introduces a bug in that if there are *no* `*.gz` files, you still get a result of 1. What specifically is the concern about variables? If it's about needing to deallocate them, consider: `countFiles() { if [[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]]; then echo "$#"; else echo 0; fi; }; countFiles *.gz` -- then your in-memory storage is on the stack, and automatically deallocated.

Comment: re: shell-native arithmetic, btw, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr

Comment: I'm happy that my question apparently was not as trivial as I thought ;-) Thank you for you comments. Yes, deallocation was the reason I didn't want to use a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Charles that parsing `ls` is not a good practice but anyway if you want to do that, you can try

```
 ls *.gz |wc -l | xargs echo "0.5*" | bc
```

Comment: I want to get the nr of processes with `ps aux` on a `mac` and do `ps aux | wc -l|xargs echo "1-" | bc|cut -c2-`. It works--